# How to tell if a series has a convergent majorant series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know that a series $\sum b_n$ is a majorant series for $\sum a_n$ if $|a_n| \leq b_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

But I don't know how to tell if a series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n-1} \cos((2n-1)x)
$$
has a convergent majorant series.

I guess I should start taking the absolute value of $a_n$ and reduce it as follows:
$$
a_n = \lvert \frac{1}{2n-1} \cos((2n-1)x) \rvert = \frac{1}{2n-1} |\cos((2n-1)x)|
$$
but I don't know what to do next.

I guess I should reduce it until I see a series that looks something like a function I know?

Right now $a_n$ looks like $\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}$. Should I know test if
$$
\frac{1}{2n-1} |\cos((2n-1)x)| \leq \frac{\cos(nx)}{n}
$$
for all $n$, and if it is, then the series $\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}$ is a majorant series, and finally check the convergence of the majorant series to see if it is a convergent majorant series?

Answer (score 2):

This one does not have a convergent majorant series, simply because it is not absolutely convergent. Still, it will be convergent for every $x \ne  k \pi$. You can show this using [Dirchlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).

Comment: When $x=\pi$ the cosine term is constant $-1$ for all $n$ so that Dirichlet's test does not apply, and indeed here the series diverges since it is the sum of the negatives of reciprocals of odd positive integers.

Comment: @coffeemath: Ah, yes, you are correct. I will make $x \ne k \pi$ in the answer. Thanks!

Comment: orangeskid-- I also didn't think it was that obvious ( given only $x$ not a multiple of $\pi$) that the partial sums of the cosines are bounded as required to apply Dirichlet, maybe some weird choices of $x$ would lead to the partial sums of the cosine terms being unbounded...

Comment: @coffeemath: It is not obvious but the partial sums  of $\sum cos((2n-1)x)$ can be calculated. I fired up wolframalpha and got $\sum_{n=1}^N \cos(2n-1) x = \frac{\sin (2 N x) } {2 \sin x}$.  I do feel better about it now... thanks for the call :-)